# Sauce Labs & Jenkins Config Setup

Tags: c#, selenium, jenkins, saucelabs

1. I have installed the SauceLabs Plugin into Jenkins.
2. I can trigger sauce connect from the slave
3. I have added the below to my solution:

   ```
   case "saucelabs":
       DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
       caps.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName,System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SELENIUM_BROWSER"));
       caps.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Version, System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SELENIUM_VERSION"));
       caps.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SELENIUM_PLATFORM"));
       caps.SetCapability("SELENIUM_STARTING_URL", "http://url/");
       break;
   ```

This is a C# Project that I pull down from source control. My problem is I have not seen any documentation from SauceLabs on how to pass in my tests. I use specrun normally.

Is anyone using SauceLabs and Jenkins? Are you passing in tests? If so  from a command line argument? What does it look like?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok For anyone looking to do this here is how I got it working.

1. Created a key in my appconfig and set it to "saucelabs"
2. In my desired capabilities for browserType I set the below:

   ```
           case "saucelabs":
               DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
                   caps.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName,System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SELENIUM_BROWSER"));
               caps.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Version,     System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SELENIUM_VERSION"));
                  caps.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SELENIUM_PLATFORM"));
               caps.SetCapability("username", "MySauceUser");
               caps.SetCapability("accessKey", "MySauceKey");
               caps.SetCapability("SELENIUM_URL", "http://probably not needed");
               _webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://ondemand.saucelabs.com/wd/hub"), caps, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300));
               _wait = new WebDriverWait(_webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600));
   ```

The SauceLabs Plugin will base the values being set. Right now I am only testing browsers and not mobile. Mobile will require more values in the desired caps.

My Jenkins setup was the same as my other projects. I execute my tests via specrun.exe and that remained the same. So if you are currently running mstest or nunit, it should be no different from what I have seen.